# Read from .msg files

Tags: c#, outlook, email, message, msg

I need to read from Outlook .MSG file in .NET *without* using COM API for Outlook (cos it will not be installed on the machines that my app will run). Are there any free 3rd party libraries to do that? I want to extract From, To, CC and BCC fields. Sent/Receive date fields would be good if they are also stored in MSG files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** I have found a 3rd party COM library called [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) which is working fine for me at the moment. If you use it via COM-Interop in .NET, don't forget to release every COM object after you are done with it, otherwise your application crashes randomly.

Answer (score 10):

There is code avaliable on CodeProject for reading .msg files without COM. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx).

Comment: it's not bad (its free & open source!) but doesnt support any of the date fields on a msg (yet)

Comment: With a slight modification this can save attachments as well (right now it just displays whether there are any, and the size).

Comment: @Steve one commenter shared the instructions for getting the sent / received date here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C?msg=2932319#xx2932319xx (scroll to the end)

Comment: @Ciaran wow, blast from the past. thankfully since then, i've never needed to go anywhere near outlook ;)

Answer (score 8):

Here's some sample VBA code using [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) that Huseyint found.

```
Public Sub ProcessMail()

   Dim Sess As RDOSession
   Dim myMsg As RDOMail
   Dim myString As String

   Set Sess = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
   Set myMsg = Sess.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:\TestHarness\kmail.msg")

   myString = myMsg.Body
   myMsg.Body = Replace(myString, "8750", "XXXX")

   myMsg.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this not a C# Topic?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has documented this: [.MSG File Format Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's a "Structured Storage" document. I've successfully used [Andrew Peace's code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/structstor.aspx) to read these in the past, even under .NET (using C++/CLI) - it's clean and fairly easy to understand. Basically, you need to figure out which records you need, and query for those - it gets a little bit hairy, since different versions of Outlook and different types of messages will result in different records...

Answer (score 1):

You can try our (commercial) [Rebex Secure Mail](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/) library. It can read Outlooks MSG format. Following code shows how:

```
// Load message
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Load(@"c:\Temp\t\message.msg");

// show From, To and Sent date
Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", message.From);
Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", message.To);
Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message.Date.LocalTime);

// find and try to parse the first 'Received' header
MailDateTime receivedDate = null;
string received = message.Headers.GetRaw("Received");
if (received != null)
{
    int lastSemicolon = received.LastIndexOf(';');
    if (lastSemicolon >= 0)
    {
        string rawDate = received.Substring(lastSemicolon + 1);
        MimeHeader header = new MimeHeader("Date", rawDate);
        receivedDate = header.Value as MailDateTime;
    }
}

// display the received date if available
if (receivedDate != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receivedDate.LocalTime);
```

More info on Sent and Received dates and how are they represented in the message can be found at http://forum.rebex.net/questions/816/extract-senttime-receivetime-and-time-zones

Answer (score 0):

If you open the .MSG file in a text editor, i believe you will find that the information you are after is stored as plain text inside the file. (It is on all the messages i have checked at least)

It would be pretty easy to write some code to parse the file looking for lines beginning with "From:" or "To:" etc. and then extracting the information you need.

If you need the body of the email as well, that may be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I believe thats .eml files .msg are binary

Comment: They are, but he is correct.  Try it and see for yourself