# Is there a free library for parsing .MSG files?

Tags: c#, email

I've seen a few examples that use the Apose.Network library but at $599 a pop my client won't sign that off

Answer (score 2):

Good suggestions: [Read from .msg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880/read-from-msg-files).