# Visual Basic 6: Read MSG files and extract content

Tags: vb6, outlook

I would like to read `MSG` file stored on the filesystem and do the following:

- Read the body text of the msg file.

  Open and save the attachments in the `MSG` file.

Is it possible using the `msoutl.olb#Microsoft Outlook 10.0 Object Library`?

I would like to avoid using [Outlook Redemption v. 4.7](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) based 
on question [MSG Read Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880/read-from-msg-files)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can.  Try adding a reference to the Outlook 10 object library and then try this code:

```
Dim OL As Outlook.Application
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Set OL = New Outlook.Application
Set Msg = OL.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\msg.msg")
' now use msg to get at the email parts
MsgBox Msg.Subject
Set OL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
```

I can't vouch for any of the methods or properties of your Outlook.MailItem object (msg) but give it a shot and see.