# Convert .msg to .pdf programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I've been trying to convert a large batch of .msg files into .pdf. So far, I've been able to leverage the Universal Document Converter and its libraries, but there's an issue: because it's basically a printer, it pops up a small dialogue box in the background between the conversion of each file, momentarily holding up the system.

I need this to be completely set-and-forget, running silently in the background. I have upwards of 3,600 messages to convert at once, and this happens at least weekly.

I've utilized the PDFsharp libraries before, but I'm still really new to them. Is it possible PDFsharp can do this, without the annoying dialogue boxes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MSG file, as in an Outlook email message?

Comment: Are you simply printing the messages to a PDF?

Comment: Yes. As in the Outlook email format.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223834/how-to-print-msg-into-pdf

Comment: And the Stack Overflow stereotypes continue. Linking to another thread that's, for certain, already been looked at.

That doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: but it is a duplicate of [How to print .MSG into PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223834/how-to-print-msg-into-pdf). for a no-code question, mainly about libraries, this will be as good as it gets :) edit a more specific problem into your question, and something useful may become of it.

Comment: How does the link not help? One answer tells you how to do it and another answers gives you actual code to do it

Comment: Not in C#. The other answer is vague, simply stating that PDFSharp could potentially be used. 

The other answer is using Aspose. I'm specifically asking if there's a way to implement this in C# using the PDFSharp library.

Comment: to which the vague answer is "basically yes, but you will need to convert msg into one of the possible input formats that this library accepts". one way is to use outlook automation to save the msg as html, and go from there, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223834/how-to-print-msg-into-pdf). But then, modern versions of outlook can save to pdf themselves, so probably outlook is not a viable option?

Comment: @Taborator we have no idea what you have or have not looked at.  Did you state somewhere in your question that you had looked at that question?  If so please point it out.  It's disappointing that "attempting to be helpful" is considered a stereotype.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the most recent version of Universal Document Converter it is possible to get rid of that dialogue:

1) open UDC preferences window and go to "Advanced" section

2) Uncheck "Show progress window while processing" feature

3) Go to "Output location" section and check "Use predefined location and file name"

By the way, I advise you to try use [FolderMill](https://www.foldermill.com/) software. It works by monitoring hot folder. So you just copy source MSG files to the "Hot Folder" FolderMill monitors. And it will automatically convert all incoming files to PDF with no user interaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, I figured out that the dialogue box I'm seeing isn't from UDC. I've already disabled all notifications in its user interface. This "Printing..." dialogue box is handled by Windows. It shows up no matter what printer you're using, virtual or real.

Comment: OK, try use FolderMill then. It converts MSG files to PDF without virtual printing technology usage.

Comment: For reasons I can't really disclose, I cannot use any third party software. Assemblies and libraries are okay, but not outside software.