# Display a saved .msg message as HTML or ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I have a problem. I need a way to import a saved .msg file from Outlook and then display this as html.

Ideally I would have an ASP:FileUpload control that the user would upload the email. Then I would want to parse this as markup so the email can be displayed in the website. I just don't know how to go about pulling this email message in and passing it as a new MailMessage object.

If I could bring the data from the file upload in as a new MailMessage object I would imagine I could read the information from the file and display this.

There has to be a way to display the contents of a .msg with C#. I can't imagine there isn't. I would REALLY like to not use third party plug-ins or .dll files. I have a feeling C# has this functionality somehow built into it. (maybe include one of the references?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read from .msg files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880/read-from-msg-files)

Comment: I saw that thread. Problem is the only off is third party applications or add-ins. I would really like to avoid using them if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a third-party library to load the MSG file, and then retrieve the content of the message? [Aspose.Email](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.email-for-.net/default.aspx) can probably do that for you.

Comment: The OP states: "I would REALLY like to not use third party plug-ins or .dll files", so I'm pretty sure he's considered it and doesn't want to do it.

Comment: Like I said. I don't know if there is anyway to do this without third party code. Again, I just need to display the email as HTML. I am pretty sure there is some way to expose the .msg file's contents.